# Fire on change event of input programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fire the change event of an input box programmatically. Basically I'm reading a value from a string and assigning it to the input and then fire the change. I've hunted through the site and none of the examples I've found seem to work. I can see the value being assigned so I know that I've successfully targeted the input but after that....nothing.

```
if (SearchString != null)
{
    //alert(SearchString);
    $('#example_filter').find("input").val(SearchString);
    $('#example_filter').find("input").trigger("change");
}
```

Anybody help please!?!?

Comment: Of course you have setted an onchange handler

Comment: seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/mPcsJ/1/  Are you getting any errors in console? could you show your on change event?

Comment: What do you expect trigger change to do? You have to post relevant code as the one for your onchange handler!

Comment: @SxChoc you need to show more of your code
1.Show onchange handler
2.Show the whole function with if(searchstring!=null) what triggers that

Comment: change handler is for select field

Answer (score 0):

Is your change handler attached by js code or html `onchange="DoSomething()"` tag?

This might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing it like this....

```
e = $.Event("keyup");
e.which = 13;
$('#example_filter').find("input").trigger(e);
```

And it worked a treat!

Thanks for your time people.